# Persistent SSH Error 'port 22: No route to host'

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh, scp

I have been trying to resolve a problem on my Windows 11 laptop dealing with openSSH server with the error message 'port 22: No route to host'. Mind you I have done the download correctly, and have it logged on and running as the local system.

It started with trying to scp some files from a remote host (A linux server) to my local machine (My laptop with Windows 11). I first got problems with timing out over port 22, which is typically due to some firewall privileges, of which I had eventually disabled windows firewall entirely to see if that would circumvent the problem, no dice.

Fortunately, it did clear up the timing out error and replaced it with a new error `port 22: No route to host` when trying to ssh back into my local machine when ssh'ed into the remote host using the command `ssh osbor@myip` and the error `Host key verification failed. lost connection`, with the command `scp sourceuser@server:~/file destinationuser@localhost:/Desktop`. When I did some digging online there was also the potential issue of the ISP simply blocking inbound connections over port 22, fine. I just changed the default port to 1100 in the 'sshd_config', this also didn't work, still the same error. At this point I was using [this website](https://ping.eu/port-chk/) to check whether or not the ports were open/listening on these ports, on which it reported that they were in fact closed. I knew this couldn't be an ISP issue because my linux machine was able to scp files from remote to local over the same network and ports just fine. All the machines I have spoken about here are connected to internet. I can provide configs if needed.

I have been struggling with using openSSH with windows for months and just need some clarification. Thank you.

Comment: Is the remote server out on the internet or just elsewhere on your local network? Why are you connecting back to your local machine? scp should only require the local-to-server connection. Connecting in from the outside usually requires port forwarding

Comment: `I have done the download correctly` what download? is `myip` your public IP, or your private "behind a NAT" IP? The latter won't work, the former would need port forwarding on your router to do be able to work. also, if your public IP is a CG-NAT address, then you're SOOL (networking is hard)

Comment: "no route to host" suggests either you haven't port forwarded on your router, or you're stuck on shitty CG-NAT